# Display non ssl url images on ssl site

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

I am trying to display images from a non-ssl url source on my ssl site through relative linking, making sure the padlock shows up green and does not message mixed content. Though I understand this might not be the best way going forward I have 2 questions:

1) I have 2 sources:

http://bc01.rp-online.de/polopoly_fs/benito-raman-fortuna-duesseldorf-2017-1.7053738.1516622253!httpImage/1633501625.jpg_gen/derivatives/d950x950/1633501625.jpg

and

http://bilder.bild.de/fotos-skaliert/prinzessin-eugenie-ist-verlobt-200668711-54556312/3,w=120,c=0.bild.jpg

If I convert the first source to:

//bc01.rp-online.de/polopoly_fs/benito-raman-fortuna-duesseldorf-2017-1.7053738.1516622253!httpImage/1633501625.jpg_gen/derivatives/d950x950/1633501625.jpg

it will not be displayed in Chrome.

If I convert the second source to:

//bilder.bild.de/fotos-skaliert/prinzessin-eugenie-ist-verlobt-200668711-54556312/3,w=120,c=0.bild.jpg

it will be displayed in Chrome and padlock shows green.

Can someone explain me the difference?

2) Is there a better way to show images from non-SSL URL's external sources in a SSL site making sure the padlock is green.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny you should post this. I had a really odd behaviour for something similar to this today and you have no choice *but* to use `//example.com/......` and this is just a (Google) Chrome thing.

The difference here is that in using `//`, it will automatically resolve to the respective protocol; which you should use and this for JS scripts, images, forms etc.

**NOTE:** If there is any mix of http/https anywhere in your code, then that too will cause havoc and will throw a message in any browser about mixed content.

Answer (score 0):

If your urls starts with "//" it means that the browser should use the protocol of the parent webpage. In your case it's https.

So your two links becames:

> https://bc01.rp-online.de/polopoly_fs/benito-raman-fortuna-duesseldorf-2017-1.7053738.1516622253!httpImage/1633501625.jpg_gen/derivatives/d950x950/1633501625.jpg

But bc01.rp-online.de doesn't have a valid https certificate.
and

> https://bilder.bild.de/fotos-skaliert/prinzessin-eugenie-ist-verlobt-200668711-54556312/3,w=120,c=0.bild.jpg

which works perfectly.

If you include http images in your https website, chrome doesn't show the "secure" green padlock because your website is not fully secure: some items may be intercepted/modified by a third party.

**To have the green padlock you should only use secure (https) images/resources. If these images are not available with https (or if their https links are broken or redirect to http) then you need to find another solution, such as hosting yourself the images.**